# LOAD DATA and ignore tab characters

Tags: mysql, csv

Want to load a tab-delimited-file into single-field text file, while ignoring and not deleting tab characters. I can only succeed in stripping the tabs (I used the bar terminator because it is not in my data):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
INFILE 'c:\\test\\test.txt' 
INTO TABLE text_rows 
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

This loads

```
"PROGRAM_NAME   PROGRAM_URL CATALOG_NAME    "
```

as

```
"PROGRAM_NAMEPROGRAM_URLCATALOG_NAME"
```

But this:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
```

Loads only this: "PROGRAM_NAME"

Comment: Please also DESCRIBE your table.

Comment: The table is just one column varchar 3000.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (txt TEXT);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.35 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA
    -> INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\test.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE test
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT REPLACE(txt, '\t', '\\t') FROM test;
+----------------------------------------------+
| REPLACE(txt, '\t', '\\t')                    |
+----------------------------------------------+
| PROGRAM_NAME\tPROGRAM_URL\tCATALOG_NAME\t    |
| PROGRAM_NAME2\tPROGRAM_URL2\tCATALOG_NAME2\t |
+----------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help - I just realized that I am stupid, and viewing the table in Navicat it seemed that the tabs didn't go through, but having tried several unsuccessful configurations, I assumed that it had failed without verifying it properly. Never assume!

Looking again, after seeing the suggestion by Akina, I did indeed get the tabs. Putting the bar character in worked just fine. Thanks for getting me straightened out!